# Moshi parse fields with the same key but different values

Tags: android, retrofit2, moshi

Our backend sends a json response that can contain different values for the same key every time.

Example of first Variation

```
{
  "title": "2",
  "profile_image": {
    "profile_image_id": "4581542",
    "sized": "media/up/2020/48/460e689e286ca46b1006b62269ee21a22b6bdabf2496506e34e5d07c5d42c20f_user_photo_160674563705555.sized.JPG",
    "sized_w": "556",
    "sized_h": "555",
    "thumb": "media/up/2020/48/460e689e286ca46b1006b62269ee21a22b6bdabf2496506e34e5d07c5d42c20f_user_photo_160674563705555.thumb.JPG",
    "thumb_w": "90",
    "thumb_h": "90"
  },
  "profile": {
    "title": "2",
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "user_online_status": false
  }
}
```

And below is an another variation of the same response. Notice the `profile_image` field is now an Array type and `user_online_status` can also be a string or a boolean. Moreover when profile_image is empty it's always an empty array. In any other case it's the object.

```
{
  "title": "2",
  "profile_image": [],
  "profile": {
    "title": "2",
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "user_online_status": "0"
  }
}
```

How can I parse such responses using Retrofit and Moshi without creating extra model classes? Can I use a custom adapter Maybe? Could you give me an example?

Comment: Have you tried asking the API developer to be consistent?

Comment: Ask your superiors to fire entire backend team, starting with their lead.

Comment: Love the comments.

Comment: No time to fire the backend team nor to get them to fix the issue we are delivering tommorow and I'm going crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backend team were not fired after all and I became the hero of the day.

My solution for the inconsistent `profile_image` field:

1. Marked inconsistent class properties to type of `Any?` in my data class
2. Implemented custom moshi adapter
3. Made use of `Map` to parse inconsistent json fields.

---

```
class SkipEmptyProfileAdapter {

    @FromJson
    fun fromJson(response: UserProfileDataResponse): UserProfileDataResponse {
        if (response.profileImage is Map<*, *>) {
            val map = response.profileImage as Map<String, String>
            response.imageUrlParsed = map["sized"]
        }
        return response
    }
}
```

Include adapter to Moshi builder

```
fun provideMoshi(): Moshi {
    return Moshi.Builder()
        .add(SkipEmptyProfileAdapter()) //the ordering matters
        .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
        .build()
}
```

Comment: A good way to get image URL from profile_image key if it is not  a empty array. Actually I'm more interested in user_online_status key, it can also be a string or a boolean. How did you work it out? Chage the type of userOnlineStatus to Any and add one more field so that can be set real value later?  same thing as before? Or is there another way to do it without adding indirect field?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom adapter that will deserialize `ProfileImage` properties manually. The adapter will be called when Moshi reaches `profile_image` property.
Two cases you need to consider:

1. The empty case `[]` this is when the API has returned a json array. This is the case where you will receive `BEGIN_ARRAY` token.
2. The desired case, where you need to deserialize each of the `ProfileImage` properties, one by one. This is when the you receive `BEGIN_OBJECT` token

The order of the cases must be at preserve to ensure that empty case is always checked first.

Read about tokens [here](https://square.github.io/moshi/1.x/moshi/com/squareup/moshi/JsonReader.Token.html).

```
class SkipEmptyProfileAdapter: JsonAdapter<ProfileImage>() {
    override fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader): ProfileImage? = when (reader.peek()) {
        JsonReader.Token.BEGIN_ARRAY -> {
           //this the case when [] is returned. Return null 
            null
        }
       
        JsonReader.Token.BEGIN_OBJECT -> {
           // here you parse the `profile_image` property 
           // here you start iterating properties from the json object until END_OBJECT is
          // found. By the time END_OBJECT is reached you should have populated the 
          // ProfileImage object 
        }
       
        else ->  null
    }

    override fun toJson(writer: JsonWriter, value: ProfileImage?) {
        writer.value(value ?: "[]")
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me check if this works. Btw when `profile_image` is empty it's always an empty array. In any other case it's the object. And one more thing. Do I have to create another adapter for the `user_online_status` inside the `profile` ?

Comment: No luck the adapter does not seem to be triggered whatsoever when added via addAdapter on Mosh builder